# Inverted transparent triangle with SVG

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes, clip-path

I am trying to make a banner. It works pretty well, but not in Firefox. How can I achieve same effect in Firefox and keep my text inside? For example, with SVG?

Example:

```css
.top-box {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 90%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 90%, 0 100%, 0 0);
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-box">
  <p>Some text ...</p>
</div>
```